# How to post and receive a file with web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Api Post method that I want to be able to accept any file type and that looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post()
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

        if (provider.Contents.Count != 1)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                "You must include exactly one file per request."));
        }

        var file = provider.Contents[0];
        var filename = file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Trim('\"');
        var buffer = await file.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
  }
```

This works in fiddler when I try to post an image to it. However, I'm writing a client library and I have a method that looks like this:

```
        public string PostAttachment(byte[] data, Uri endpoint, string contentType)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endpoint);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = contentType;
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        var stream = request.GetRequestStream();
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        stream.Close();

        var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
           return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }            
    }
```

Whenever I try to post an image using this, I'm getting a UnsuportedMediaType error. I'm assuming it's because my image isn't Multi Part Content? Is there an easy way to make my request of the correct type?

If I have to change my web api post method, is there an easy way of doing that without writing files to the server and keeping it in memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `MultipartFormDataContent` from the `System.Net.Http` namespace will allow you to post multipart form data.

```
private async Task<string> PostAttachment(byte[] data, Uri url, string contentType)
{
  HttpContent content = new ByteArrayContent(data);

  content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(contentType); 

  using (var form = new MultipartFormDataContent())
  {
    form.Add(content);

    using(var client = new HttpClient())
    {
      var response = await client.PostAsync(url, form);
      return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
  }
}
```