# How to post an image to Azure Function as a parameter of request?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I am building an API to process an image using Azure Function and C#.
How can I post an image to Azure Function as a parameter in request body?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are thinking of HTTP trigger, you will receive `HttpRequestMessage`, which you can use to extract files the same way you would do in ASP.NET Web API controller.

There are many links explaining that, e.g.

- [How to post and receive a file with web api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34168395/how-to-post-and-receive-a-file-with-web-api)
- [Uploading a File in ASP.Net Web API](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2b481f/uploading-a-file-in-Asp-Net-web-api/)
- [Similar SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38406043/1171619)